# Overloading + Operator results in the exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: c++, object, polymorphism

I am trying to overload + operator in the following simple code. However, every time I am getting the same error as *Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)* and the code does not output anything. What exactly is the problem which is causing this runtime memory error?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex{
private:
    int real;
    int imaginary;
public:
    Complex() : real(0), imaginary(0){}
    void getData(int real, int imaginary);
    Complex* operator +(Complex Obj);
    void showData();
    };

void Complex :: getData(int real, int imaginary){
this->real = real;
this->imaginary = imaginary;
}

Complex* Complex :: operator+(Complex Obj){
Complex* temp;
temp->real += real + Obj.real;
temp->imaginary += imaginary + Obj.imaginary;
return temp;
}

void Complex :: showData(){
cout << real << " + " << imaginary << "i";
}

int main(){

Complex Number1, Number2;
int real, imaginary;

cout << "Enter real and imaginary of first complex number" << endl;
cin >> real >> imaginary;
Number1.getData(real, imaginary);

cout << "Enter real and imaginary of second complex number" << endl;
cin >> real >> imaginary;
Number2.getData(real, imaginary);

Complex *Number3;
Number3 = Number1 + Number2;
Number3->showData();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Complex *temp` is a pointer without any initialization nor allocation. That's a good reason to get a segmentation fault (aka access violation). Please, remove the `*` (and replace `->` by `.`) and try again.

Comment: `Complex* Number3 = new Complex();` I tried allocating memory dynamically by calling default constructor. But it's still the same.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the `operator+` should return `Complex` instead of `Complex*`. It's fully sufficient that the return value is allocated on stack - no heap allocation necessary.

Comment: It actually works fine on the stack. But, I want to try it out by doing on the heap.

Comment: Why? That's totally unusual. I can confirm that it works fine on stack: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7a60c9d724545c6). ;-)

Comment: Although this makes my eyes hurting... It works on heap as well: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d78f13d0e34f7014). ;-) Did you oversee anything?

Comment: Actually I am trying to understand the concept of pointers and dynamic memory in C++. I am not very much thorough in them in the context of the class. However, please try by doing on the heap.

Comment: Forgot to delete the dynamically created object. 
PS: Thanka a lot

Comment: OK. In this case, I warmly recommend not to fiddle with raw pointers too much but to invest into smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, and `std::weak_ptr`). Containers like `std::vector` and friends are a good option for heap storage as well. Raw pointers (with `new` and `delete`) are somehow an inheritage from C and good for all kinds of trouble. At best, don't use them if anyhow possible.

Comment: The missing `delete` is not a serious issue in your specific case. The OS (Windows in your case) cleans up your process memory after exit. A missing `delete` will cause a memory leak but shouldn't cause an access violation (not in your situation). [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cafeb54e04d2482)

Comment: So, I am using Clion IDE, I just noticed that it outputs the correct answer in the terminal but did not produce any output in Clion without Delete. Though, I know that OS does this job automatically but still, it's a good practise to delete it and then make it point to `nullptr`.

Comment: Btw. you didn't check for errors after input. So, I got this working without input as well but it resulted in strange ouput as the computation was done with uninitialized variables. `if (!(cin >> real >> imaginary)) { cerr << "Houston, we got a problem!\n"; return 1; }` would handle this.

Comment: And a stylistic hint: `getData()` is an unusual name for a _setter_. I agree that the object gets data but usually the view is from outside: You _set_ a value to object. ;-)

Comment: Concerning CLion. Please, add something after `Number3->showData();`: either a `cout << '\n';` or a `cout << endl;`. I assume the reason for missing output in CLion is the missing output buffer flush but not the `delete`. I guess it's rather incidential that it works with `delete` but not without.

Comment: I am wondering if there exists a mechanism in CPP which allows you to create such classes whose objects can be created only on heap @_@

Comment: Yes, there is. Make all constructors private and provide a `static` `create()` member function instead. (I learnt this from `gtkmm`.) ;-) Btw. `private` constructors would finalize the class as side effect. If this is not intended you have to make them `protected` instead.

Comment: You may write a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). That's allowed and encourage in SO.

Comment: This interface means that you can't write `Number1 + Number2 + Number2`. Addition usually does not work that way.